# wrong time with jquery timeago on safari

Tags: jquery, datetime, safari, timezone

I've been looking for a solution for a while now but I can't find one.

I use the plugin jquery timeago https://timeago.yarp.com/ to render my dates as "x time ago", and on chrome, firefox works well, except on safari.

On safari it puts me 7 hours behind the exact time.

However, I fill in the date in iso format, and it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
let datetime = new Date(conversation.lastMessage.createdAt).toISOString();
let timeAgo = jQuery.timeago(datetime);
```

Here is the output :

On Safari (incorrect):

```
conversation.lastMessage.createdAt // 2021/02/10 17:23:37
datetime // 2021-02-10T23:23:37.000Z
timeago // 7 hours ago
```

On Firefox (correct):

```
conversation.lastMessage.createdAt // 2021/02/10 17:23:37
datetime // 2021-02-10T16:23:37.000Z
timeago // 1 minute ago
```

I specify that timezone is "Europe/Paris".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- The issue isn't with timeAgo, but with how you are using the `Date` constructor to parse the string you provided.
- The string format you're passing in is not directly supported by JavaScript.  Instead of `"2021/02/10 17:23:37"` it should be `"2021-02-10T17:23:37"`  Refer to [*Date Time String Format*](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) in the ECMAScript specification.
- The EMCAScript spec [also states](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date.parse):

  > ... If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. ...

  Thus, when you pass a non-standard format to `Date.parse` or as a string to the `Date` constructor, you are likely to get different results from different browsers.
- I cannot explain *why* Safari is giving you the result it is.  The value appears to be interpreted as UTC-6.  Are you sure the time zone of that computer/device is set as you expected?
- However, despite the above points, Safari in particular has implemented the ECMAScript spec incorrectly in past versions.  From Safari 14 forward, strings like `"2021-02-10T17:23:37"` are correctly interpreted in the local time zone.  Safari 13 and earlier incorrectly interpreted that as UTC.

Thus, if you want to be standards compliant and don't need to support older browsers, then you can adjust your input string to match the spec before parsing:

```js
const input = "2021/02/10 17:23:37";
const d = new Date(input.replaceAll('/','-').replace(' ','T'));

console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.toISOString());
```

However, if you also want to support older browsers then I suggest you parse the string yourself:

```js
var re = /(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
var input = "2021/02/10 17:23:37";
var a = input.match(re).slice(1, 7).map(x => +x);
a[1]--; // months are 0-11
var d = new Date(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);

console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.toISOString());
```